# Distribution on percentile from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

If I have the following dataframe, df, with millons variables

```
id      score
140    0.1223
142    0.01123
148    0.1932
166    0.0226
..       ..
```

My problem is,

> How can I study the distribution of each percentile?

So, my idea was divide score into percentiles and see how much percentage corresponds to each one.

I would like to get something like

```
percentil countofindex  percentage
  1          154.000       %20  
  2          100.320       %17
  3          250.000       %21
 ...
```

where countofindex, is the number of differents Id, and percentage is the percentage that represent the first, second,.. percentil.

So for this, I get df['percentage'] = df['score'] / df['score'].sum() * 100, but this is the percentage of all data.

Comment: Seems like pandas [quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) method seems like it would be applicable here. It would help to see your expected output and code for what you've tried so far to make a [mcve]

Comment: This is 3 questions here. I don t think it respect stackoverflow standards... Anyway try numpy.percentile first or pandas quantile second. Then for histogram matplotlib can help you with the hist method of an axis.

Comment: @VincentBénet sorry, I edit my question

Comment: Still not a minimal reproducible example... What have you tried?

Comment: Furthermore, note that "how much percentage corresponds" to a percentile does make much sense statistically. The (say) 20th percentile value/score is by definition the value `x` such that `F(x)=0.2`, where `F` denotes the CDF, and the probability of a single value in a continuous distribution is zero. So what should that percentage correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

To get the percentage of each score you can get the [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of all scores and divide each one by it:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'score': [0.1223,0.01123,0.1932]})

df['percentage'] = df['score'] / df['score'].sum() * 100
```

```
     score  percentage
0  0.12230   37.431518
1  0.01123    3.437089
2  0.19320   59.131393
```

To sort you can use [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html?highlight=insert#pandas-dataframe-insert):

```
df.sort_values(by=['percentage'], ascending=False)
df.insert(1, 'percentile', range(1,len(df)+1))
```

```
     score  percentile  percentage
2  0.19320           1   59.131393
0  0.12230           2   37.431518
1  0.01123           3    3.437089
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I would like to have the percentage of data for each percentile

Answer (score 0):

let's go through the following example.

```
print(df)
           0
0   0.127975
1   0.146976
2   0.721326
3   0.003722

df[0].sum()
1.0
```

Now, to create the chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
langs = [str(round(i[0]*100,2)) for i in df.iloc]
data = [round(i[0]*100,2) for i in df.iloc]
ax.bar(langs,data)
plt.ylabel("Percentiles")
plt.xlabel("Values")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

If you want to add it to the dataset, you can use the code below.

```
df['Percentiles (%)']=df.apply(lambda x: round(x*100,2))

print(df)
          0  Percentiles (%)
0  0.127975            12.80
1  0.146976            14.70
2  0.721326            72.13
3  0.003722             0.37
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can I know how many index are in each percentil? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, are you wondering about the number of data falling into percentiles?

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain it well, but what I'm looking for is to see the distribution that each percentile has.